# How to move reserved instance to a new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I am currently running an instance on a reserved instance.

That instance now I dont want to use but I want to still not lose that instance. Just shutdown.

How can I move the reserved instance that I paid long term to a newly created instance ?

Thanks.

Comment: Reserved Instances are merely billing discounts. If you want to keep the instance, you can simply Stop the instance. There is no need to create a 'new' instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html):

> Reserved Instances are not physical instances, but rather a billing discount that is applied to the running On-Demand Instances in your account. The On-Demand Instances must match certain specifications of the Reserved Instances in order to benefit from the billing discount.

So you can terminate your current instance and if the new one match with your reserve (instance type, region, etc) then the reserve is applied automatically.

Comment: if i terminate, then everything is lost is it ? i dont want to lose the whole setup

Comment: You can create an AMI before terminate the instance. When needed to re-create the setup, just launch a new instance using that AMI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and if it works will award the answer to you

Comment: I confirm with AWS, its applied after terminated and recreating the new instance. Thanks.